# CMake make library require cxx standard

Tags: c++, c++11, cmake, c++14

I try to make my library target to depend on c++14. How can i achieve, that the targets, that link against my library target also depend on c++14?

I tried to use:

```
add_library(lib SHARED ${FILES})
target_compile_options(lib INTERFACE CXX_STANDARD 14)
```

This works to build the library, but when i try to compile other targets using `lib` C++14 is not activated.

I am aware, that there are other methods, but i can't get them to work. Namely there is:

```
set_target_properties()
```

The reason for this is, that the library headers make use of generalised lambda capture and template aliases like `std::remove_reference_t` and similar, that are in the standard library since c++14.

Comment: So if other targets use that library, they are de facto using c++14 as well. How about directly specifying the c++ standard on them then? It would be odd if simply using a library had the side effect of changing the very language your program uses.

Comment: That is what I do at the moment, but i think there are more elegant ways in the recent `cmake` versions. The cuda and mpi targets manage to set multiple flags automatically.

Comment: Your library has .h or hpp files which are compiled by the users. Check the needed compatibility level there.

Comment: @ddbug what do you mean by compatibility level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for (CMake version >= 3.8) is the following:

```
target_compile_features(lib PUBLIC cxx_std_14)
```

or, with CMake versions above 3.1, by specifying explicitly the features you need, f.i.:

```
target_compile_features(lib PUBLIC cxx_alias_templates)
```

The syntax you used is incorrect for setting the required standard. As a side remark, `PUBLIC` is used instead of `INTERFACE` since you want to compile the library itself with C++14 as well.

More details in the [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_gbl/CMAKE_CXX_KNOWN_FEATURES.html).

Comment: Looks like he will need this and his existing CMake since it appears his code is using `CXX_STANDARD` to conditionally compile variants of code.